# Django - Global navigation in base.html using model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-tagging

I have a number of templates that extend *base.html*. I want the *base.html* template to house my global navigation and have the text and links in the global navigation be based on a model Division (i.e. the `CharField` in the model will be used as the button text in the global nav, and the id will be used to build the URL). I thought tags might work, but what I end up with is this (yes, I'm new to Django and Python):

*current_tags.py*

```
from django import template
# Import your model
from libs.display.models import Division
from django.db import models

register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def do_get_divisions(self):
    d = Division.objects.all()
    mylist = []
    for each in d:
        mylist.append(str(each.DivisionValue))
    return my list
```

I'm attempting just getting the text value in each object to print at this point because I can't get or work with the objects in the template, as you'll see below.

*base.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" />
</head>
<body>
{% load current_tags %}
<p>{% do_get_divisions "" %}</p> **THIS ACTUALLY PRINTS mylist**

{% for each in do_get_divisions %} **THIS DOESN'T PRINT ANYTHING**
    <p>{{ each }}</p>
{% endfor %}  
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do global nav based on a model in Django. I basically want to get all the Division objects and put them into a `<ul>` to use as my global nav in *base.html*. I am not that familiar with Django, but my *views.py* don't help me because I am rendering other templates, not *base.html*, which are extending *base.html*. For what it's worth, here's one *views.py*, where */display/info.html* template extends *base.html*:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from apps.pulldata.models import Data
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404

def info(request, group_id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Data, pk=group_id)
    s = group.XInGroup.all()
    return render(request, 'display/info.html', {'Group': group, 's': s})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put a templatetag into another. Your for-loop is a templatetag that expects the name of an element in your context to iterate over.

If you want to handle the navigation in a template tag you should consider using [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Inclusion tags are functions that use templates to render their data.

A very basic implementation could look something like this:

tags.py

```
@register.inclusion_tag('navigation.html')
def navigation(selected_id=None):
    return {
        'navigation': Division.objects.all(),
        'selected':selected_id,
    }
```

In your templatetag file you create a dictionary with the navigation items and optionally the currentl selected item to highlight this navigation element.

navigation.html

```
<ul>
{% for item in navigation %}
  <li{% if item.id == selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.DivisionValue }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the navigation.html uses the dictionary from the python function as context so you start with simply iterating over the navigation.

base.html

```
{% navigation %}
```

or

```
{% navigation current_division.id %}
```

In the base.html you call the inclusion tag like a normal template tag. if you want to highlight the current item you add its id as a argument.

Comment: Thanks for turning me toward inclusion tags. I've included navigation.html fine, but I'm not getting navigation.html to work with my model it seems. `% load current_tags %}
<ul>
        <li>{{ navigation }}</li>
        <li>Nothing shown</li>
</ul>` is my navigation.html and I even simplified current_tags.py to `from django import template
from libs.display.models import Division
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('display/navigation.html')
def navigation(self):
        return 'Hello'` Is there some critical step I'm missing to return the tag back to navigation??

Comment: Actually, the only way I could get navigation.html into base.html was with `{% include 'display/navigation.html' %}`.....just doing `{% navigation %}` didn't work.

Comment: I will ask in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595237/django-template-reading-objects-through-inclusion-tag)...thanks.

Comment: Have you used `{% navigation %}` or `{{ navigation }}`?

Comment: I did `{% navigation %}` but I thought that was referring to the template, not the tag. Didn't realize the tag was rendering the template;thought the template was pulling in the tag. Got that part straightened out thanks to a comment over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595237/django-template-reading-objects-through-inclusion-tag). All working well now. Thanks!